# Redirect back to previous page after login in django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

There is a button in blog detail view that asks user to login to comment, but after login user is redirected to home page because in `settings.py` I declared:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "projects:home"
```

I searched and I found this could be a solution:

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Please login to reply</a>
```

but this even didn't work.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are half-way there: When you add ?next={{request.path}} to your a tag, you are creating a 'next' variable and assigning the current path to it. But that alone isn't enough for your desired result; you still need to actually **use** that variable in your login form.

You haven't shown us your login template, but I assume it's a basic form. Add a hidden button to the login form, and have it use the 'next' variable that was captured in your a tag. Put the following code inside your login form tag, after everything else, but before closing the the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}" />
```

When a user submits the Login form, the template will use the value stored in request.GET.next, which was captured from your a tag.